# Return on Equity Vs Stock Returns

Tags: stocks

I have a invested in Hexaware Stock (NSE-India) around 1-Jan-2018 at 340Rs -- Now the LTP of the stock as of Today(31-Dec-2019) is 334.70Rs.

But I was going thru Company ratios and noticed the ROE for this is very good around "29.16" for 2018 -- Close price of Dec-2018 is 331Rs..

How come my return are negative while company is showing good ROE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Return on equity (ROE) is a measure of financial performance calculated by dividing net income by shareholders' equity.
>   [- investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/returnonequity.asp)

So long as the net income is positive, ROE will be positive (assuming the denominator net assets is also positive).

More importantly, ROE isn't related to share price - it is mathematically related to measures like profits, equity and debt.

On the other hand, share prices are not mathematically related to those measures (profits, equity, debt, etc). Share prices could be thought of as what the market thinks the company is worth - kind of like equity, but a lot more nebulous. Share prices are also very sensitive to investor sentiment.

Now, changes in equity over a period of time can be calculated mathematically from the underlying numbers. Stock market returns, however, are simply the difference between the prices at the start and end of a given period. Again, there is no mathematical link between changes in ROE and changes in stock price.

Bottom line: returns from share investment are not related to ROE or to changes in ROE. If you bought when the price was high and now the price is low, *you* have a negative return on that investment. During that same period, the company itself could have done quite well, though perhaps it has lost its shine (not growing earnings fast enough, starting to lose money, sudden loss of key personnel, general stock market downturn, etc).